# Using GADTs to build trees with different node types and parent-child relationship rules

Tags: haskell, tree, gadt

I am trying to build an XML generator for a custom XML structure using the simple [`xml`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/xml) package. Here is a sample XML fragment:

```
<Response>
  <Answer>Hello World</Answer>
  <Play loop="3">http://example.com/a.mp3</Play>
  <SendAnswer dest="someuri">
    <Answer>Something</Answer>
    <Play>someuri</Play>
  </SendAnswer>
</Response>
```

In this custom XML there are rules specifying what elements may be nested under each kind of element. Is it possible to define a GADT to build XML fragments that restrict the structure based on these rules? The rules simply list what kind of parent-child relationships are allowed (e.g. Response cannot be a child of any other element, SendAnswer can be a child of Response, etc).

Here is how far I got: https://gist.github.com/4104499

When executed, it outputs:

```
<Response>

  <Speak loop="2">

    http://example.com/a.mp3
  </Speak>
</Response>
```

However, I feel this approach has a number of shortcomings:

1. The data definition of MyXMLElement (line 31) is going to require as many lines as there are valid parent-child relationships. In a different implementation, it would be possible to just list the legal children of an element, and check at legal relationships at runtime. I chose this approach (using GADTs) so that invalid XML trees would be illegal at compile time.
2. The interface given by eval is very limited: it does not allow arbitrary nesting (even when following the parent-child relationship rules); it does not allow adding XML attributes as required.

I would like to know if this problem is a good fit for a solution using GADTs. If it is, how can it be better designed?